# Как добавить в var функцию?

Tags: функции, ajax

Как в это:

```
var dataString = 'name='+ name +
'&email=' + email + '&phone=' + phone;
```

---

добавить это:

```
 function emailCheckout(form){
     var me=simpleCart;counter=1;
     form.appendChild(me.createHiddenElement("currency",me.currency));

     for(var current in me.items){
     var item=me.items[current];

     form.appendChild(me.createHiddenElement("name_"+counter,item.name));
     form.appendChild(me.createHiddenElement("quantity_"+counter,item.qty));
     form.appendChild(me.createHiddenElement("price_"+counter,item.price));

     var descriptionString="";
     for(var field in item){if(typeof(item[field])!="function"&&field!="id"&&field!="qty"&&field!="price"){

     descriptionString=descriptionString+",
 "+field+":
 "+item[field]}}descriptionString=descriptionString.substring(1);
     form.appendChild(me.createHiddenElement("item_description_"+counter,descriptionString));
     counter++}
     }
```

---

чтоб сработало это:

```
 $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "checkout.php",
       data: dataString,
```

---

И по завершении произошла очистка форм.

**Обновление**

Спасибо, использую ее, но по завершению вылазит окно "отправленно", и если не перезагрузить страницу, оно снова вылазит при выводе формы (полей для заполнения нет).

```
  success: function() {
    $('#bag').html("<div id='message'></div>");
    $('#message').html("<h2>Contact Form Submitted!</h2>")
    .append("<p>We will be in touch soon.</p>")
    .hide()
    .fadeIn(1500, function() {
      $('#message').append("<img id='checkmark' src='images/check.png'
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно использовать ещё один параметр ajax запроса - success, где указать вашу функцию очистки. success - функция, которая выполняется в результате удачного завершения ajax запроса.

Comment: спасибо, использую ее
но по завершению вылазит окно "отправленно"
и если не перезагрузить страницу, оно снова вылазит при выводе формы (полей для заполнения нет)


   
   
   
      success: function() {
        $('#bag').html("<div id='message'></div>");
        $('#message').html("<h2>Contact Form Submitted!</h2>")
        .append("<p>We will be in touch soon.</p>")
        .hide()
        .fadeIn(1500, function() {
          $('#message').append("<img id='checkmark' src='images/check.png'